# Add custom view to LinearLayout Dynamically using data binding(MVVM)

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, mvvm, android-databinding

How can custom layout be added in LinearLayout if you are using data binding?

Here is my activity layout.
I want to add multiple layouts dynamically to "layoutOptions" linearLayout.

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<data>

    <variable
        name="mainViewModel"
        type="com.mihir.facilities.viewmodel.FacilitiesViewModel" />
</data>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutOptions"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"/>

</layout>
```

In my viewModel, I have inflated the layout I want to add, but I'm not sure how can I access "layoutOptions" linearLayout in my "FacilitiesViewModel" to call "addView" method.

Comment: i want to also do same thing have you found any thing for that ?